# Output a files contents with a filename stored in a variable

Tags: bash, file, cat

I have a script that gathers filenames under various directories, greps them for a specific pattern, and sends that output to another script. I am having a problem with getting the contents of the file, I either get nothing or "no such file or directory errors". It is possible for the filenames to have spaces in them, so I have tried:

1.

```
$FILENAME="cat $FILENAME"
echo $FILENAME | grep "pattern"
```

2.

```
FILENAME=$(printf %q "$FILENAME")
$(cat "$FILENAME") | grep "pattern"
```

3.

```
FILECONTENT=$(<"$FILENAME")
echo "$FILECONTENT" | grep "pattern"
```

But these and all the combinations of these I tried don't seem to work, Ill always get empty file contents before the grep. Could someone point out what Im missing?

Comment: have you tried just `grep "pattern" "$FILENAME"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$FILENAME="cat $FILENAME"
echo $FILENAME | grep "pattern"
```

Is wrong because we set a variable by omitting the '$' prefix. Furthermore you would be setting the `FILENAME` variable to the string `CAT $FILENAME`. Instead:

```
FILENAME=$(cat $FILENAME)
echo $FILENAME | grep "pattern"
```

But then in the next name you would be grepping the contents of the file, which can be done without storing the contents of the file in its own variable with just:

```
grep "pattern" "$FILENAME"
```

**In your second attempt:**

```
FILENAME=$(printf %q "$FILENAME")
$(cat "$FILENAME") | grep "pattern"
```

You are, for some reason, storing the variable back in itself. Then you cat out the contents of that file into grep. Which is also unnecessary (see solution above).

**Finally, in your last attempt:**

```
FILECONTENT=$(<"$FILENAME")
echo "$FILECONTENT" | grep "pattern"
```

Instead of `cat` to get the contents into the `FILECONTENT` variable you went with a redirect. Either way it's superfluous since the content of the file doesn't need to be stored in a variable, it's already in the file itself. Your second line is right on the money, but I suspect that the redirect failed in the first line so it's a wash.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth testing if the filename is correct to begin with:

```
[[ -f "$FILENAME" ]]
```

will do that. So

```
if [[ -f "$FILENAME" ]]; then
    grep "$pattern" "$FILENAME"
else
    echo "$FILENAME does not exist" >&2
fi
```

Will let you know what's up. Of course, if you use the `grep "$pattern" "$FILENAME"` approach, grep will let you know about files that don't exist, too. It's a question about how much you want to control error conditions.